# Problems transferring information from one part of a function to another

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, average

While working on my program I have run into a problem where the information stored in Menu option 1 is not being transferred to Menu option 2. As you can see it is correctly stored when in menu one. When it returns to go to menu option 2 its like it never went to option 1.

update #1:
some suggestions I've had is to understand scope? from what I can tell the program is not passing the data along to its parent program even though I've typed out return in each of the definitions.

```
#Must be able to store at least 4 grades
#Each class can have up to 6 tests and 8 hw's
#Weighted 40%*testavg 40% hw average attendance is 20%
#User must be able to input a minimum grade warning
#after each test the your program must calculate the students average and issue warning if necessary

##Define the Modules##
import math

def menu (a): #2nd thing to happen 
    menuend = 'a'
    while menuend not in 'e':
        menuend = raw_input("Type anything other then 'e' to continue:\n")
        print "What would you like to do ?"
        menudo = 0
        print "1 - Enter Courses\n2 - Select Course to Edit\n3 - Save File\n4 - Load File\n5 - Exit\n"
        menudo = input("Enter Selection:")
        if (menudo == 1):
            menuchck = 0
            menuchck = raw_input("\nYou have entered #1 (y/n)?:\n")
            if menuchck in ["Yes","yes","y","Y"]:
                x = m1()
            else:
                print "I'm sorry,",nam,",for the confusion, lets try again\n"
                menu()
        elif (menudo == 2):
            menuchck1 = 0
            menuchck1 = raw_input("\nYou have entered #2 (y/n)?:\n")
            if menuchck1 in ["Yes","yes","y","Y"]:
                x = m2()
            else:
                print "I'm sorry,",nam,",for the confusion, lets try again\n"
                menu()
        elif (menudo == 3):
            print "Entered 3"
        elif (menudo == 4):
        print "Entered 4"
        else:
            print "Anything Else Entered"

def course(): #3rd thing to happen 
    b = {}
    while True:
        while True:
            print "\n",name,", please enter your courses below ('e' to end):"
            coursename = raw_input("Course Name:")
            if (coursename == 'e'):
                break
            will = None
            while will not in ('y','n'):
                will = raw_input('Ok for this name : %s ? (y/n)' % coursename)
            if will=='y':
                b[coursename] = {}
        print "\n",name,", current course load:\n",b
        coursechck = None
        while coursechck not in ('y','n'):
            coursechck = raw_input("Are your courses correct (y/n)")
        if coursechck =='y':
            return b
        else:
            b = {}
            print

##Menu Options##
def m1():
    a = course()
    return a

def m2():
    print "Excellent",name,"lets see what courses your enrolled in\n"
    print x
    return x

###User Input Section###
name = raw_input("Enter Students Name:\n")
a = {}
menu(a)

raw_input("This is the end, my only friend the end")
```

Comment: Changed a few things

    elif (menudo == 2):
                menuchck1 = 0
                menuchck1 = raw_input("\nYou have entered #2 (y/n)?:\n")
                if menuchck1 in ["Yes","yes","y","Y"]:
                    x = a
                    x = m2(x)
                    return x
as well as 

    def m2(x):
        print "Excellent",name,"lets see what courses your enrolled in\n"
        print x
        return x

this seemed to get me back on track to where i need to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if-elif blocks in the do==1 case, you write `m1()`, but for the last case, you write `x=m1()`. You should have the latter everywhere (by typing `m1()` you only run the function, but do not store the returned x anywhere).

By the way, you can avoid this if-elif confusion using `if chck in ["Yes","yes","Y","y"]:`

Comment: Aye, i noticed it still trying to go through and find the solution on my own lol. Wish i had had a good cheat sheet for commands. using _doc_ is hard to do in idle hehe

Comment: aye have done that in the past, its not really a cheat sheet. So much that if you know already exactly what something is called or how it works you can find what your looking for. Having no background in programming or what things are called its hard to surf through the hundreds of pages to maybe stumble upon something that does what you want it to.